# How to move storage account from one location to another

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-storage-account

I accidentally selected the location as east us for my storage account , Now I'm trying to move this particular storage account to my my desired location , but when I'm using Azure resource Mover and select Source location as east us It doesn't show any resources to select

Answer (score 0):

You can't move storage account across regions using Azure Resource Mover as it supports limited resources.

To move storage account across regions, refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-move?tabs=azure-portal).